# Rails routing problem. Changing resource from plural to singular give "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

** Update: This question is about a bug in Rails: **

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/267

** End update. **

I tried to use singular resources (as per [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)) because I like better url of the type

```
/user/new
```

compared to

```
/users/new
```

So in my routes.rb I changed from

```
resources :users
```

to

```
resources :user, :controller => 'users'
```

Now in my view the command

```
form_for(@user) do |f|
```

give the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users"}
```

Any clue?

This is the output of rake routes

```
user_index GET    /user(.:format)          {:action=>"index",  :controller=>"users"}
           POST   /user(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
  new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new",    :controller=>"users"}
 edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit",   :controller=>"users"}
      user GET    /user/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show",   :controller=>"users"}
           PUT    /user/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
           DELETE /user/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy",:controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: Have you tried `resource :user` instead of `resources :user`

Comment: Do you have got `UsersController` or `UserController` ?

Comment: I have UsersController, plural. Everything is how it is generated by "scaffold"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is about a bug in Rails:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/267

Answer (score 3):

Try `resource :user` instead of `resources :user`, as it is a singular route.
A singular resourceful route generates these helpers:

- new_user_path returns /user/new
- edit_user_path returns /user/edit
- user_path returns /user

So, `users_path` would now be `user_path`.

Comment: With "resource :user" I am getting the error "undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x997cda0>:0x9971c5c>".

Comment: The error is generate by "form_for(@user) do |f|" command. Is Rails trying to use "users_path" instead "user_path" ignoring the routes configuration? I start thinking that maybe is better to stick with plural resources...